# Assign session number to a series of transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
CREATE TABLE [Transaction](
    [TransactionID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LocationID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [KioskID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TransactionDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [TransactionType] [varchar](7) NOT NULL,
    [Credits] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StartingBalance] [int] NULL,
    [EndingBalance] [int] NULL,
    [SessionID] [int] NULL
);
```

Please refer to this fiddle for the sample data:
[Link to SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/07779/3/0)

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to assign a session number to a sequence of transactions in a single update.

A "Session" is defined as a number of deposits and purchases ending with a withdrawal. A Session has sequential transactions consisting of:

- 1 to n deposits (TransactionType = 'D'),
- 0 to n purchases (TransactionType = 'P') and
- 0 or 1 withdrawals (TransactionType = 'W')

With the same LocationID and KioskID. A session can end with a 0 balance or a withdrawal. First deposit with no session starts one. Only P transactions have balances. For D and W they are NULL.

LocationID, KioskID, SessionID must be unique.

I'm really hoping that there is a SQL way of doing this. I'd hate to have to loop through hundreds of millions of transactions to set sessions procedurally.

Comment: It's more a business logic thing, I suggest you to implement that at your BL layer. You can control it by checking if the current transaction being inserted/updated ill "close" the session and handle the appropriate operations for it. Maybe you can find usefull to create a endsession timestatmp or flag to your session table

Comment: I have no control over data entry. I'm collecting it from a couple of hundred existing locations.

Comment: I already have a request into the device people to provide a session id, but it's at best a year off.

Comment: I hate to say it but a \*cof\* trigger is the best \*chokex20 and choke\* way to do it. You can create a session table and handle it (create/insert) in a trigger at transaction table.

Comment: Do not ask us to go to another site to understand your problem and question, please post all necessary information *here*.  It is OK to *also* post to and link to a SqlFiddle, but do not make your question and its answer dependent on it.  StackExchange has no relation to SqlFiddle and no control over whether it is up or even exists in the future.

Comment: Does TransactionID relaiably indicate the order of the transactions or must the TransactionDate be used for that?

Comment: Also, what version of SQL Server?

Comment: @RBarryYoung yes, it does. SQL Server 2012.

Comment: The data you are providing at the SqlFiddle, is not useful for testing, as there are no instances of more than one session at the same LocationID+KioskID.

Comment: Unfortunately, SQLFiddle only allows 8000 chars for DDL + inserts and the real test data is a few million rows per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
;WITH markSessions as
(
    SELECT  *,
        CASE 
            WHEN TransactionType='W' THEN 1 
            WHEN TransactionType='P' And EndingBalance=0 THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END As SessionEnd
    FROM Transactions
)
SELECT  *,
    SUM(SessionEnd) OVER(PARTITION BY LocationID, KioskID ORDER BY TransactionID) 
        + 1 - SessionEnd As SessionID
FROM markSessions
```

No triggers, cursors or client code needed.

---

If you actually want to set the SessionID in the table, then you'd use an UPDATE statement like this:

```
;WITH markSessions as
(
    SELECT  *,
        CASE 
            WHEN TransactionType='W' THEN 1 
            WHEN TransactionType='P' And EndingBalance=0 THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END As SessionEnd
    FROM Transactions
)
UPDATE markSessions
SET SessionID = SUM(SessionEnd) OVER(PARTITION BY LocationID, KioskID ORDER BY TransactionID) 
        + 1 - SessionEnd
```

---

I am unable to test it, but the following should take into account pre-existing SessionIDs

```
;WITH markSessions as
(
    SELECT  *,
        CASE 
            WHEN TransactionType='W' THEN 1 
            WHEN TransactionType='P' And EndingBalance=0 THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END As SessionEnd
    FROM Transactions
)
UPDATE markSessions
SET SessionID = SUM(SessionEnd) OVER(PARTITION BY LocationID, KioskID ORDER BY TransactionID) 
        + 1 - SessionEnd 
        + COALESCE(MAX(SessionID) OVER (PARTITION BY LocationID, KioskID), 0)
WHERE SessionID Is NULL
```

Note that this will only work if all new rows (those without SessionIDs) have higher transaction IDs than the Pre-existing rows (those that already have SessionIDs).  It definitely *NOT* work if new rows were added with TransactionIDs, lower than the highest TransactionID already assigned a SessionID.

If you may have that situation, then you likely will have to reassign the old TransactionIDs.

Comment: It works. Can't say I fully understand how, though. Also, this would re-assign the session number with every run. Data is added daily and I'd want to continue the SessionID on subsequent runs. Is that doable?